# Wordpress: Hide Menu Item Based on User Meta Value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a field in my user meta called dues_balance.  I want to hide a menu item if that value is more than zero.

```
    function hideMenuDues(){
        $user_id=get_current_user_id();
        $key='dues_balance';
        $single=true;
        $dues_balance=get_user_meta($user_id,$key,$single);
        if ( ! empty( $dues_balance ) {
             // check value
           if ($single > 0) {
                //hide the menu item

           }
         } else {
             //hide menu item
           }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, you'll likely need to provide the HTML in addition to your JavaScript in order for us to help solve your problem. If you've tried anything so far that hasn't worked, it would also be helpful to mention it. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I decided to just create a new user role to work around my problem.  I need to get a a good PHP book (I'm a .NET guy) and learn the basics.  Thanks again.